# Split datetime64 column in dataframe on year

Tags: pandas

I have a column in my dataframe containing data in the datetime64 format.
so example: 2005-02-01 00:00:00 and 2007:02-02 00:00:00.

I want to split this into multiple columns which per year. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Its hard to understand your question. Can you post a sample output that you would like to get?

Comment: what do you mean by "which per year"?